# Turn emoji back to previous default after upgraded to iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, emoji

Hello I just upgraded to iOS 8.3. My emoji is now default to kind of yellow colour, which is super annoying. Any ways I could set it back to previous default colour. Thank you!

Comment: hold your finger on the emoji, it will bring up other color options for many of the emoji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try holding down on the emoji you want and see if it brings up a menu to pick the skin color like this:

[image: emoji]

That feature is mainly only available on the more "human" looking emojis. Doing this will now set the default of that emoji to the color you chose, so I guess you could go through all of them and pick the one you want and they should stay as the new default instead of having to pick from the yellow one every time, but there isn't a way to "revert back" to 8.2 and earlier styles.

Comment: I know hold can change but should have a setting to set default colour : (. The current yellow looks sick. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @juanitofatas Once you set the color to send it once it will remember and that color will be the "default" the next time you open the Emoji keyboard.